# Trying to create a pi estimator in R

Tags: r, function

This is a homework problem. I am brand new to R just FYI
This is the problem:
R does have a built-in constant `pi`. Here we will use random numbers to estimate the value of 
π. Create a function `approx.pi()` that takes a parameter `N`. Inside this function, code the 
following steps:

- (1) set `j` equal to 0.
- (2) start a for loop with counter `i` that repeats `N` times.
- (3) Inside the for loop, generate two random uniform numbers `x` and `y` between -1 and +1 
  using `runif()`.
- (4) If `x^2 + y^2 < 1` then add one to `j`.
- (5) End the `for` loop.
- (6) Return the estimate of π which is `4×j/N`

and this is the code I have:

```
approx.pi <- function(N) {
    j <- 0
    for (i in N) {
        x <- runif(1,-1,1)
        y <- runif(1,-1,1)
        if (x^2+y^2< 1)  {
            j=j+1
        }
    }
    return(4*j/N)
}
approx.pi(N=5)
```

I am getting some number values returned but they are no where near pi can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know in the instructions it seemed like I should incorporate i in N in the for loop

Comment: In other languages besides R, I think it is common to write `for (i in N)` but that's not the syntax here unless `N` is a vector.

Comment: I changed i in N to j in N and now Im getting approximately 4 when N equals a very large number I guess thats pretty close?

Comment: Change the for to `(i in 1:N)` and then use N=10000.  This returns 3.1412

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Wikipedia uses this same example for the [Monte Carlo Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) entry.

Answer (score 1):

This code will only run for 1 value i = N.

```
for (i in N) {}
```

You need to change to

```
for (i in 1:N){}
```

I have tried edited code and got the output

```
approx.pi <- function(N) {
    j <- 0
    for (i in 1:N) {
        x <- runif(1,-1,1)
        y <- runif(1,-1,1)
        if (x^2+y^2< 1)  {
            j=j+1
        }
    }
return(4*j/N)
}
```

Here is my output. (you use 5 is too small).

```
> approx.pi(5000)
[1] 3.188
> approx.pi(5000)
[1] 3.1488
> approx.pi(5000)
[1] 3.1344
> approx.pi(5000)
[1] 3.1672
> approx.pi(5000)
[1] 3.1632
> approx.pi(5000)
[1] 3.1152
```